# Prevent a specific attribute from rendering on DOM node in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Using **data-test** attribute to test whether the components renders without crashing on jest test cases. But the attribute is being rendered on DOM node also. Is there any way to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this package:

```
babel-plugin-react-remove-properties
```

And set this in your babelrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        ["react-remove-properties", {"properties": ["data-test", "data-foo", /my-suffix-expression$/]}]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will remove all attributes that you list in production builds.

Comment: Thanks, that works :). But when I try to add "height" to the properties array, it also removes the height props from passing to component.

`<Component height={height} />`

Then I use the height props in styled component to set height of the element like `height: ${props => props.height};`. Since height prop is removed on babel transpile, height for the element is not set. Help me on fixing this.